# How to find height?

Tags: physics

> The figure below gives the speed $v$ versus time $t$ for a $0.520$ kg object of radius $6.20$ cm that rolls smoothly down a $30^\circ$ ramp. The scale on the velocity axis is set by $v_s = 4.0\text{ m/s}$. What is the rotational inertia of the object?

[image]

Someone said the formula is, 
$$mgh  = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 + \frac{1}{2} Iw^2$$

I don't see height in this problem, though. Can it be found?

Comment: That equation is an energy relationship. You can use that equation if you like, but it will be difficult. Just find the area underneath the curve (line). That will be your height.

Comment: Please type out text from images. Also, you can upload images directly when you ask a question. Just click the little icon that looks like a mountainside with a sun. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate the velocity to recover the distance.
$$
 \int v dt = x
$$
Read the chart to recover the velocity function. The velocity is constant, and after $1$ second, is $3.5$ $m$/$s$:
$$
v(t) = 3.5t
$$
The distance traveled, in meters, is
$$
\int_{0}^{1} 3.5t\, dt = \frac{7}{4}t^{2} \Big\lvert_{0}^{1} = \frac{7}{4}(1) - 0 = \frac{7}{4}
$$

(Thanks to @user435909 for the proof read.)

Comment: Isn't v 3.5 because of rise/run?

Comment: @user435909: Yes indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter Szilas. Yes. This is why graphs should always be labelled! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

$mgx = (1/2)mv^2 + (1/2)I \omega ^2$,

find $I$.

An object rolls down a ramp of 30° inclination. Let O be the starting point.

Consider an axis vertically downward through O, let it be the positive x-axis.  Measure x along this axis.

Initially  $t= 0, x(t=0) = 0$ and $v(t=0) = 0$, where $v(t)$ is the velocity of the particle moving down the ramp.

Energy conservation:

Loss of potential energy: $mgx$, counted positively vertically downward,

$=$

gain in kinetic energy $(1/2) mv^2 + (1/2) I\omega ^2$.

The kinetic energy consists of two parts:

Linear motion down the ramp, $(1/2) mv^2$, and rotational motion around the CM, $(1/2) I\omega^2$.

Let $s$ be the distance from $O$ down the ramp.

$Sin (30°) = 1/2 =  x/s$,   i.e.  $s = 2x$.

We have:

(×)  $mg(s/2) = (1/2)mv^2 + (1/2)I \omega^2$.

Let's look at the $v$-$t$ graph given in the problem.

We find $dv/dt  = a$ (constant).

With the initial conditions $t=0, x(t=0) = 0$, and $v(t=0) =0$, integration yields:

1) $v(t) = at$;

2) $s(t) = (1/2) at^2$, and

eliminating $t$ to find $s =s(v)$:

3) $s(v) = (1/2)a(v(t)/a)^2 =(1/2) (v(t))^2 /a$.

Replacing $s$ in equation (×):

$(1/2)mgv^2/(2a) = (1/2) mv^2 + (1/2)I\omega^2$ .

With  $\omega = r v$, the above equation becomes:

$mgv^2/(2a) = mv^2 + I r^2 v^2$.

Canceling $v$ and solving for $I$:

$$I = \frac{mg - 2am}{2ar^2}$$.

Check:

For $I = 0$  there is  no rotational energy.

$a = g/2 = 5 [m/sec^2]$ which is the value of the $g$ component along the ramp,  $a = g$ $cos (60°)$ .

In this problem $a = 3.5 [m/sec^2]$, less than $5 [m/sec^2]$ due to the rotation.